# One more relation with spherical spinors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spherical-harmonics, spinors

Let's have the spherical spinors:
$$
\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \pm \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2l + 1}}\begin{pmatrix} \pm \sqrt{l \pm m +\frac{1}{2}}Y_{l, m - \frac{1}{2}} \\ \sqrt{l \mp m +\frac{1}{2}}Y_{l, m + \frac{1}{2}} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
How to prove the relation
$$
(\hat {\sigma} \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \pm \frac{1}{2}} = -r\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \mp \frac{1}{2}}?
$$
I tried to rewrite the $(\hat {\sigma} \cdot \mathbf r )$ as
$$
(\hat {\sigma} \cdot \mathbf r ) = r\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta ) & \sin(\theta )\,e^{-i\varphi } \\ \sin(\theta )\, e^{i \varphi } & -\cos(\theta ) \end{pmatrix},
$$
but it's hard to use recurrence relations for associated Legendre functions after that. Is there some hint which simplifies the proof?

Maybe, I can first show that $(\hat {\sigma} \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \pm \frac{1}{2}} = -ra\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \mp \frac{1}{2}}$,
because the parity of the left side is opposite to the parity of $\mathbf {Y}_{j, m, l = j \pm \frac{1}{2}}$, and $(\hat {\sigma} \cdot \mathbf r )$ commutes with rotation operator, because refers to the scalar pdoduct?